# Objectless class in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

How to create a class that doesn't allow to create its object,doesn't have any pure virtual functions, no private constructor. But can be inherited by derived class and member functions can be redefined in c++?is it even possible to create such class?

Comment: What is the exact problem that you are facing? Is the Q based only on Curiosity??

Answer (score 2):

One way is to make the constructors `protected`.

---

Another way is to make the destructor and `operator new` protected. Public destructor is required for creating objects with static and automatic storage duration, as well as for `delete` (but not for `new`).

Example:

```
struct X {
protected:
    ~X();
    static void* operator new(size_t);
    static void* operator new[](size_t);
};

int main() {
    X x;          // error: destructor is non-public.
    X* p = new X; // error: operator new is non-public.
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate. On first thought, I'd have expected "constructor" and "protected"....